# Logstash: create new event in filter

Tags: events, elasticsearch, copy, logstash

When filtering events in logstash (20+ attributes) i would like to create new event which would have one parameter from original event and store it into other ElastiSearch index.

I know this is possible using `clone` filter plugin. But i don't want to manually remove all attributes from original events except the one I need.

Also i could just clone that event (i'm will store new event in separate elasticsearch index) but that will duplicate unneeded attributes.

Is there any filter plugin for this purpose? Or some hidden feature? Or maybe `clone` filter plugin handles removal of all attributes from cloned messages?

Comment: Have you seen prune{} ?

Answer (score 0):

ElastAlert is a simple framework for alerting on anomalies, spikes, or other patterns of interest from data in Elasticsearch.

http://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elastalert.html

Comment: Would benefit from a summarized how-to from the given link.  Link-only (or nearly link-only) answers are frowned upon; see [help].